# YouTube player with ionic

Tags: angularjs, video, ionic-framework, youtube

I am trying to get a video player that will play youtube videos on my ionic project. I installed this [plugin](https://github.com/Glitchbone/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer) and not sure this is what I am looking for. I need to record how long they watched the video for. Then when they get to a certain point they get rewarded with a credit. I am able to get the YouTube video to play using this.

```
$scope.videoClick = function (resp) {
        $cordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer.openVideo(resp);
    }
```

but cant control anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a YT.Player to be able to control anything with the video. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference is where I referenced my information.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.